# Custom Intent is not getting called

Tags: dialogflow-es

Only default intent gets called. Custom intent is not called at all.

[Training Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFTg6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things going wrong here as you did not provide a lot of information.

I assume you have the following entities and you `saved your intent`

- DepartureLocation (including Indore)
- ArrivalLocation (including Mumbai)
- FlightType (including non-stop)

Please check if you have no `input Contexts` attached to the intent, `you saved your intent` before testing and the `agent has finished training`. I re-created your intent, please see the attached images for clarification. When a parameter is not directly specified by the user Dialogflow will prompt the user, asking for this parameter if it has been set as required.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiCmL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNblK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46LBJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfBMA.png)